# Sockets: large message performance

Tags: c++, performance, sockets

I have a doubt regarding the use of Berkeley Sockets under Ubuntu. In terms of performance and reliability which option is best? To send a high amount of messages but with short length or to send a low amount of messages but this ones with a large size? I do not know which is the main design rule I should follow here.

Thank you all!

Comment: Are you using SOCK_STREAM or SOCK_DGRAM sockets?

Comment: Since TCP is a stream, the message sizes are determined by the protocol, not your application.  The stream -- as whole -- doesn't have a size.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of reliability, unless you have very specific requirements it isn't worth worrying about much.  If you are talking about TCP, it is going to do a better job than you managing things until you come across some edge case that really requires you to fiddle with some knobs, in which case a more specific question would be in order.  In terms of packet size, with TCP unless you circumvent [Nagel's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm), you don't really have the control you might think.

With UDP, arguably the best thing to do is use [path MTU discovery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_MTU_discovery), which TCP does for you automatically, but as a general rule you are fine just using something in 500 byte range.  If you start to get too fancy you will find yourself reinventing parts of TCP.

Answer (score 1):

With TCP, one option is to use the `TCP_CORK` socket option.  See the `getsockopt` man page.  Set `TCP_CORK` on the socket, write a batch of small messages, then remove the `TCP_CORK` option and they will be transmitted in a minimum number of network packets.  This can increase throughput at the cost of increased latency.

Comment: It looks like this is Linux-only though (which may not be a problem).

Answer (score 0):

Each network message has a 40-byte length header, but large messages are harder to route and easier to lose. If you are talking about UDP, so the best message size is Ethernet block, which is 1496 bytes long, if yiu are using TCP, leave it up to network layer to handle how much to send.

Answer (score 0):

Performance you can find out yourself with [iperf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/iperf). Run a few experiments and you will see it yourself. As for reliability as far as I understand if you use TCP the TCP connection guarantee that data will be delivered of course if the connection is not broken.

Answer (score 0):

"In terms of performance and reliability which option is best"

On a lossy layer, performance and reliability are almost a straight trade-off against each other, and greater experts than us have put years of work into finding sweet spots, and techniques which beat the straight trade-off and improve both at once.

You have two basic options:

1) Use stream sockets (TCP). Any "Messages" that your application knows about are defined at the application layer rather than at the sockets. For example, you might consider an HTTP request to be a message, and the response to be another in the opposite direction. You should see your job as being to keep the output buffer as full as possible, and the input buffer as empty as possible, at all times. Reliability has pretty much nothing to do with message length, and for a fixed size of data performance is mostly determined by the number of request-response round-trips performed rather than the number of individual writes on the socket. Obviously if you're sending one byte at a time with TCP_NODELAY then you'd lose performance, but that's pretty extreme.

2) Use datagrams (UDP). "Messages" are socket-layer entities. Performance is potentially better than TCP, but you have to invent your own system for reliability, and potentially this will hammer performance by requiring data to be re-sent. TCP has the same issue, but greater minds, etc. Datagram length can interact very awkwardly with both performance and reliability, hence the MTU discovery mentioned by Duck. If you send a large packet and it's fragmented, then if any fragment goes astray then your message won't arrive. There's a size N, where if you send N-size datagrams they won't fragment, but if you send N+1-size datagrams they will. Hence that +1 doubles the number of failed messages. You don't know N until you know the network route (and maybe not even then). So it's basically impossible to say at compile time what sizes will give good performance: even if you measure it, it'll be different for different users. If you want to optimise, there's no alternative to knowing your stuff.

UDP is also more work than TCP if you need reliability, which is built in to TCP. Potentially UDP has big payoffs, but should probably be thought of as the assembler programming of sockets.

There's also (3): use a protocol for improved UDP reliability, such as RUDP. This isn't part of Berkeley-style sockets APIs, so you'll need a library to help.